# Rails 3 Assign A Container Div Within Loop

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, loops, html

say I'm looping through an array of products, how would I go about assigning a container div within that loop. For instance I want output like so:

```
<div class="page">
  <p>product1</p>
  <p>product2</p>
  <p>product3</p>
  <p>product4</p>
</div>
<div class="page">
  <p>product5</p>
  <p>product6</p>
  <p>product7</p>
  <p>product8</p>
</div>
```

I tried something like this:

```
<% @products.each_with_index do |product, index| %>
  <% if index%4 == 0 %>
    <div class="page">
  <%end%>
  <p><%= product.data %>
  <% if index%4 == 0 %>
    </div>>
  <%end%>
<% end %>
```

But as expected it will only surround every 4th product with the container. I'm thinking that I'm going to need two loops in order for this to work, but how can I do this without duplicating data?

**Edit**

When using alternatives to each_with_index is there any way to keep a track of the index using this method? There are also some conditional attributes that get set based on the index value.

For example:

```
style=<%= index == 0 ? "top:5px;" : ""%>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Rails method to split an array into groups of equal size is [`ary.in_groups_of(number)`](http://rails.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/CoreExtensions/Array/Grouping.html#M000833)

```
<% @products.in_groups_of(4, false) do |group| %>
  <div class="page">
    <% group.each do |product| %>
      <p><% product.data %></p>
    <% end %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

Much nicer in [Haml](http://haml.info/) :)

```
- @products.in_groups_of(4, false) do |group|
  .page
    - group.each do |product|
      %p= product.data
```

You can get the absolute product index with `@products.index(product)` or the group index with

```
<% @products.in_groups_of(4, false).each_with_index do |group, group_index| %>
```

Comment: See the edit details. Also I agree the HAML is much nicer to look at but sadly 95% of my application is written using ERB and it might be a bad idea to up and start using something else unless I change all the existing views to HAML.

Comment: Added a note for getting the absolute index.

Comment: Great, I didn't know about absolute index. However, I don't suppose we can get it working for the page container? I would like to apply styling to only the first page container for instance.

Comment: That works via the `group_index` (see answer). It's `0` for the first group, `1`for the second and so on.

Comment: Awesome it works now, this answer is a little cleaner than what I got working with orzechowskid's answer so I'll accept this one instead.

Answer (score 3):

```
<% @products.each_slice(4) do |slice| %>
  <div class="page">
    <% slice.each do |product| %>
      <p><%= product.data %></p>
    <% end %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

Comment: This also worked, is there any significant difference between this and in_groups_of? Also I wish I could give you bonus points for wearing Hei's face :)

Comment: `in_groups_of` is a Rails specific, but `each_slice` is a built-in Ruby method for `Enumerable` http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Enumerable.html#method-i-each_slice

Answer (score 2):

Another approach:

```
<% while group = @products.take 4 %>
  <div class="page">

  <% group.each do |product| %>
    <p><%= product.data %></p>
  <% end %>

  </div>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<div class="page">

<% @products.each_with_index do |product, index| %>
    <p><% product.data %></p>

    <% if index % 4 == 3 %>
        </div><div class="page">
    <% end %>
<% end %>

</div>
```

(edit: forgot my end  tag!)

Comment: Aha I knew there was a way to do it. Good catch on the 4 == 3 part by the way, I must have been thinking Java syntax